# AlertDialog not showing, and no error message

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-alertdialog, phonegap-plugins

What is wrong with my `AlertDialog`? `Logcat` only gets to ***"after builder set items"***, then it stops and there is no error message. Rest of app continues without issue. Can't figure out why `AlertDialog` won't show.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.cordova.getActivity());
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "after new AlertDialog");
builder.setTitle(title);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "after builder set title");
CharSequence[] choicesAsCharSeq = choices.toArray(new CharSequence[choices.size()]);
builder.setItems(choicesAsCharSeq, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // The 'which' argument contains the index position
        // of the selected item
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Index #" + which + " chosen.");
        String result = "";
        result = "" + which;
        // ActionSheet.this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, result));
    }
});
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "after builder set items");
builder.show();
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "after builder show");
```

Comment: You mention logcat in your tags. So, where is the logcat?

Comment: probably you call dialog from appwidget or non-UI thread.

Comment: I suppose the question doesn't have to do with logcat itself.

Comment: @AlexKucherenko you might be right. this is in phonegap. I'm using this line to declare my class: `public class ActionSheet extends Plugin {`

Comment: but if I use `new AlertDialog.Builder(this.cordova.getActivity())` should it be on the Main thread?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my plugin to extend CordovaPlugin instead of Plugin and the problem went away.

Answer (score -1):

u have to write

```
builder.create().show();
```

instead of

```
builder.show();
```

Comment: Show will create the dialog automatically if it hasn't yet been done.